# Validate number of items being posted ASP using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, asp-classic

I have a ASP page with Javascript. It is a totally dynamic page, so I cannot say on how many values will get posted or submitted. But I am sure that the first field will be Request Number and the last field will be the Submit button, in between there should be multiple of 3 fields to be posted. So if the user is making one entry, the field count should be Request Number + 3 fields + Submit Button, total of 5 values to be submitted. In between the multiple of 3 can be any.

I need to validate this before the data is posted after pressing the Submit Button. If for example, the number of fields is less than 5 , it should not post and give error, etc,etc...

Valid number of fields will be minimum 5 or 8 or 11 or 14 or 17 or 20 or 23 or 26 or 29, etc,etc....

Kindly help me with a Javascript function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `n >= 5 AND (n - 2) mod 3 = 0`?

Comment: can you be more detailed? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you post your existing JavaScript code?

Comment: there's no check as of now, the page will post whatever they entered to the post ASP page and the error pops up there and when they go back, nothing is there because the fields were all dynamically created.

Comment: ok here i got the number of input fields in the form being submitted through this javascript and this is inside a validate JS function which will run when the submit button is pressed. How will I check if the fields are 5 or 8 or 11 or 14, etc,etc.                      `var e = document.forms["myForm"];` 
`e= e.getElementsByTagName('input');`

Comment: `e.length` would be `n`. You need to `if ((e.length - 2) % 3 !== 0) { alert("Number of fields is invalid"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap all the values in an array.
Then post your values array to ASP page and parse the array in ASP

Comment: posting to the ASP page is okay. The code works fine but I need to restrict them to go the post page because the fields are dynamically created and they are entering lot of data, if the validation is done on the post ASP page, they cannot revert back what they have entered, so I need to stop them from posting data unless the field count is ok.

Comment: exactly, you should validate your forms with jquery and put all your validated values in an array and then post to ASP.